# React userContext & BrowserRouter gives export 'default' (imported as 'UserContext') was not found in './UserContext' (possible exports: UserContext)

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to combine BrowserRouter from the W3School tutorial here: https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_usecontext.asp with Recat Hooks UseContext.

I have created a file named UserContext that I want to use in my App. However, I get an error message when I try to import and use it.

**Error:**

```
Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in ./src/App.js 16:38-58

export 'default' (imported as 'UserContext') was not found in './UserContext' (possible exports: UserContext)
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
// or send to an analytics endpoint. Learn more: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/measuring-performance/
reportWebVitals();
```

**App.js**

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Layout from "./pages/Layout";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import Blogs from "./pages/Blogs";
import Contact from "./pages/Contact";
import NoPage from "./pages/NoPage";
import UserContext from "./UserContext";

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <UserContext.Provider value="Hello from context">
          <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
            <Route index element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="blogs" element={<Blogs />} />
            <Route path="contact" element={<Contact />} />
            <Route path="*" element={<NoPage />} />
          </Route>
        </UserContext.Provider>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**UserContext.js**

```
import { createContext } from "react";

export const UserContext = createContext(null);
```

**pages/Blogs.js**

```
const Blogs = () => {
    return <h1>Blog Articles</h1>;
  };
  
  export default Blogs;
```

**pages/Contact.js**

```
const Contact = () => {
    return <h1>Contact Me</h1>;
  };
  
  export default Contact;
```

**pages/Home.js**

```
const Home = () => {
    return <h1>Home</h1>;
  };
  
  export default Home;
```

**pages/Layout.js**

```
import { Outlet, Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Layout = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/blogs">Blogs</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/contact">Contact</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

      <Outlet />
    </>
  )
};

export default Layout;
```

**pages/NoPage.js**

```
const NoPage = () => {
    return <h1>404</h1>;
  };
  
  export default NoPage;
```

What can I do to include UserContext ?

Comment: Either add export default in your userContext or import { UserContext } from "./..."

Comment: Search the difference of export and export default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UserContext` was not default export in `UserContext.js`.
Only default exports can be imported like `import UserContext from "./UserContext";`.

Either change in `UserContext.js` to

```
export default UserContext = createContext(null);
```

or while importing in `App.js`, destructure the module `./UserContext.js` like

```
import { UserContext } from "./UserContext";
```

Answer (score 1):

in `UserContext.js` your are using named export, in `App.js` replace your UserContext with below snippet.

`import { UserContext } from "./UserContext";`

Answer (score 0):

```
import { UserContext } from "./UserContext";
```

or

```
export default const UserContext = createContext
```